# bundle key returns null when I am taking a photo

Tags: android

I am using ro start an intent for capturing an image from the camera:

```
public void takePhoto(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         try {

             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
             f = createImageFile(); // creates a new image file into which I want to store the photo
             bundle.putString( "currentPhotoPath", f.getAbsolutePath() );
             intent.putExtras(bundle);
             startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
```

the `f.createImageFile` crates an empty Image object into which I want to store the photo taken from the camera. I ma trying to pass on the bundle the path of this image object like this:

```
bundle.putString( "currentPhotoPath", f.getAbsolutePath() );
```

then I use this code to get the result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE ) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                String currentPhotoPath = bundle.getString("currentPhotoPath");
                File takenPhoto = new File("currentPhotoPath");

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                   if(takenPhoto.length() <= 0) {
                       takenPhoto.delete();
                   }
                   this.checkForUploads();
                }
                else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    takenPhoto.delete();
                } 
            }       
        }
```

I was expecting to find in the   `data.getExtras()` the key "currentPhotoPath" which holds the path to my new Image object, but it is always null. Instead the only key I get is data which I think it contains the actual bitmap data.
I have seen similar question on so an d I think I am doing it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen similar question on so an d I think I am doing it the right way.

Sorry, but no.

Extras that you put into an `Intent` go where that `Intent` goes. In your case, it goes to some activity that has an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `<intent-filter>`. What that code does with the extra is up to the developer of that activity. In your case, since you invented a new `Intent` extra on your own, your extra will be ignored, as the developer of the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity is not going to know to look for it.

The `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()` is a completely different `Intent` from the one that you use with `startActivityForResult()`. In particular, there is no requirement for extras that you put on the `startActivityForResult()` `Intent` to be included in the `Intent` response from the other app.

Comment: thank you, it seems I have misunderstand how to use Intent. If I read correct your answer, the way I am starting the intent is wrong so the the Intent I  receive is not the one I created. If this is the case what is the correct way to create an Intent for taking a photo an passing data to it?

Comment: @Christoforos: "the way I am starting the intent is wrong so the the Intent I receive is not the one I created" -- the `Intent` that you receive in `onActivityResult()` will almost **never** be the one that you created and used with `startActivityForResult()`. Certainly you should **never** assume that you will get back `Intent` extras that you put on the outbound `Intent`. If you want to hold onto pieces of data, such as a filesystem path, hold onto it yourself.

Comment: Sir please help me in this data binding problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/52947775/6891563